# does mahout0.7 still support both in-memory and MR KMeans clustering?

Tags: mahout, k-means

Does mahout-0.7 still support both in-memory and MR KMeans clustering? In its earlier release, it has a KmeansClusterer for in-memory clustering and KmeansDriver for MapReduce clustering. However, the KmeansClusterer seems to be removed from mahout0.7

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in-memory KMeans was removed from Mahout 0.7. You can see examples on how to use MR KMeans in examples for Mahout in Action, that [were adapted for Mahout 0.7](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/mahout-0.7).